# static SEO friendly page generated from react with redux, I need only index page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, seo, redux

I have web app built on react, redux, nodejs, scss, ... I would like to generate static page from index of the web app. What library would you choose? The home page need to be indexed, but I would like to keep it DRY. The best would be to render the page and the react components would be fully functional. One way would be to render the items and then replace with react components, but it seem redundant for me.

Answer (score 2):

If it is a truly static page I would consider not using React for it at all; alternatively you could look at server side rendering to process your React on the server and output HTML. Look into [renderToString](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#reactdomserver.rendertostring).